# How big is the "freemium" advantage in Skyforge?

Tags: skyforge

In Skyforge you can get a premium abo to increase reward rates.

- +50% Sparks , Credits and other resources
- +50% building resources for pantheon quests
- +25% Myrrh Drops when donating credits to the pantheon
- Ability to receive Sparks of Evolution when you play maxed class
- Free teleportation across locations

Seems quite unimportant considering you can only have 1 character and the weekly spark limit.

Is this a bonus for leveling only?

Is there exclusive content?

I feel like I missed something because it feels so underwhelming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least one additional advantage: You are getting every day some energy batteries for free. Those are needed for researching resistance which are needed for invasions.

There is some exclusive content that you can/ could buy with support packages (it unlocks directly two additional classes right away, gives you a mount, title, starting weapons).

Players who are paying are ahead in prestige, but that just means they get the available content slightly fast. On the other hand, they have a huge disadvantage as well. Since the main free prestige push method is to boost the chapels (which are just adding stamina and might), they are missing out on real stats (strength/ spirit/ valor/ luck) compared to others. How is that a disadvantage? The scaling system. If two people with different prestige play together, the system is adjusting the stats. The lower player will get a boost in all stats, if they play now together, the lower player that didn't push his prestige with money is actually stat vise stronger. The second disadvantage is, that you can't by proficiency. High boosted prestige players can't equip the items that are dropping, thus they are weaker again.

A user who decides not to spend anything on the game has no disadvantage compared to people who are paying, it will just take him longer to get certain things. He will NEVER catch up in prestige, but that number is not representing the strength of a player, just estimating it.

Answer (score 2):

At present, the bonuses you listed are the extent of the Premium bonus. While there might be future additions to the bonus, it is unlikely they will have a much larger impact on gameplay than what there is now.

The intention is for Premium to be a 'catch up' pay mechanic. A Free-to-play player will be at no disadvantage in comparison to a paying player, in the long run, but a paying player can pay to achieve their weekly caps faster. Ideally, the free player is one who can devote more time to the game, and the paying player is someone who works too often or other circumstances that prevent them from playing as often or for as long.